# Kendo UI Grid - Add new record shows 0 as ID

Tags: kendo-ui, odata, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using the Kendo UI Grid with ASP.NET MVC, Entity Framework and OData.
I have also the Record ID inside the grid - so far so good.

But when I click on "Add new record" in the toolbar the ID column shows me a 0 while I'm editing the data.

And after I click on the "Update" button it doesn't change to the correct ID (which has been returned by the service):

```
{  
    "odata.metadata":"http://localhost:61534/api/$metadata#AssetList/@Element",
    "ID":17,
    "ManufacturerName":"TEST",
    "Name":"TEST",
    "SerialNumber":"TEST",
    "AssetStateID":1,
    "AssetStateName":"TEST",
    "NextCalibration":"2013-07-11T09:08:28.298Z"
}
```

When I refresh the page/browser the correct ID is shown.

Here's my Post Method:

```
public override HttpResponseMessage Post(AssetListViewModel item)
{
    // #### MG: CREATE ASSET
    RSAMS.WebUI.Models.Asset asset = new Asset();
    asset.Manufacturer = item.ManufacturerName;
    asset.Name = item.Name;
    asset.SerialNumber = item.SerialNumber;
    asset.AssetStateID = 1; // IN USE
    asset.NextCalibration = item.NextCalibration;
    db.Asset.Add(asset);
    db.SaveChanges();

    // #### MG: RESPONSE
    item.ID = asset.ID;
    item.AssetStateID = asset.AssetStateID;
    var response = Request.CreateResponse<AssetListViewModel>(HttpStatusCode.Created, item);
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("OData", new { id = item.ID }));
    return response;
}
```

And here's the datasource js (part of it):

```
dataSource: {
type: "odata",
pageSize: 25,
serverSorting: true,
serverPaging: true,
transport: {
    create: {
        url: "/api/AssetList",
        dataType: "json"
    },
    read: {
        url: "/api/AssetList",
        dataType: "json"
    },
    update: {
        url: "/api/AssetList",
        dataType: "json"
    },
    destroy: {
        url: function (data) {
            return "/api/AssetList([RW-PARAM])".replace("[RW-PARAM]", data.ID);
        },
        dataType: "json"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Field will display "0" text, because this is the default value of the "RecordID " property (this is default behavior). It also supports setting its value after the data is retrieved.What you can do is to clear the value manually:

```
 function onGridEdit(e) {

        if (e.model.isNew()) {
            e.model.set("RecordID", null);
        }
}
```

This code needs to be placed in the grid edit event handler.